# How to call a function in jQuery on window resize?

Tags: jquery, function

I've this code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function larg(){
            var larghezza = $(document).width();
            $("p.width").text("The width for the " + larghezza + 
                " is px.");
            });

            $(window).resize(function() {
            larg(); 
            });
            </script>
```

I would like to call the function "larg" on window resize, but it doesn't work..
How to do that??

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't declare functions that way, use it like this.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(larg);

 $(window).resize(larg);

 function larg(){
  var larghezza = $(document).width();
  $("p.width").text("The width for the " + larghezza + " is px.");
 }
</script>
```

EDIT: changed code a bit, thanks commenters

Comment: +1. I think `$(document).ready(larg); $(document).resize(larg); function larg(){ ... }` should also work.

Comment: @Eddie Correct. As would `$(window).resize(larg);`.

Comment: What about if I want to pass a variable to the function e.g. `function larg(foo){}` I tried `$window.resize(larg(myVar));` but no results.

Comment: Did you declare the var outside the scope of the anonymous functions? It works when you declare it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UVXF3/

Comment: Old question, but shouldn't you define the `function` before using it?

Answer (score 1):

Please call the following method:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```