# call a function using resize()

Tags: jquery

I want to add and event listener to call a function whenever my window resize, but somehow it doesnt work! I tried these codes but none worked!

```
$(function(){$(window).resize(titleResize);});

$(function(){$(window).resize(titleResize());});

$(window).resize(titleResize);

$(window).resize(titleResize());
```

any idea?

BTW it's my titleResize function:

```
function titleResize() {
        maxHeight = 0;
        $("div.lae-entry-text-wrap > h3").each(function(){
            titleHeight = $(this).height();
            if (titleHeight > maxHeight){
                maxHeight = titleHeight;
            }
        });
        $("div.lae-entry-text-wrap > h3").css("height", maxHeight);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function in jQuery on window resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312696/how-to-call-a-function-in-jquery-on-window-resize)

Comment: Check console for error

Comment: there is no error in console, it seems there wont be any event listener at all!

Comment: May browser cached old code, So press ctrl+F5 to clear cache

Comment: @Mohammad no luck!

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen that one did'nt help either!

Comment: @amirvaziri Does other event listener working?

Answer (score 1):

**Try Following**

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
alert('Window Is Resized')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this will work, but when i call my function, it won't!

Comment: function titleResize() {
            maxHeight = 0;
            $("div.lae-entry-text-wrap > h3").each(function(){
                titleHeight = $(this).height();
                if (titleHeight > maxHeight){
                    maxHeight = titleHeight;
                }
            });
            $("div.lae-entry-text-wrap > h3").css("height", maxHeight);
        }

Comment: What it means `$("div.lae-entry-text-wrap > h3")`

Answer (score 1):

**In Following `Script` your function is calling**

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
debugger
titleResize();
});
   function titleResize() {
   alert('Function titleResize() Called');
   maxHeight = 0; 
   $("div.lae-entry-text-wrap > h3").each(function(){ 
   titleHeight = $(this).height(); 
   if (titleHeight > maxHeight)
   {
   maxHeight = titleHeight; 
   } 
   });
   $("div.lae-entry-text-wrap > h3").css("height", maxHeight); 
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){ //Your code });
```

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    console.log('resize')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also got same issue you can use this type of code for your error

```
 $(window).resize( () => {
        let Width = $(window).width();
        if (Width > 910) {
            $(".navbar1").hide();
         }
    })
```